# List all rows that do not have 2 matching unique ids

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to keep track of an `Add Log` and `Subtract Log` for a list of items and create a list of items still in stock based of of what items have been removed using the `Subtract Log`. I want the `Add/Subtract Log Results` to show all items that do not have a matching unique ID (ColA) in the `Subtract Log` unless a item was returned and added a second, third, forth, etc. Time to the `Add Log`. If the item is then added to the `Subtract Log` again it should be removed from the Add/Subtract Log Results sheet

The current formula that I am using is

`=UNIQUE({QUERY(QUERY({UNIQUE('Add Log'!$A$2:$D); UNIQUE('Subtract Log'!$A$3:$D)}, "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col1 <> '' AND Col2 <> '' AND Col3 <> '' AND Col4 <> '' GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4", 0), "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 WHERE Col5 = 1", 0); QUERY(QUERY('Add Log'!$A$2:$D, "SELECT A, B, C, D, COUNT(A) GROUP BY A, B, C, D", 0), "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 WHERE Col5 > 1", 0)})`

For some reason if I delete the info in row 11 the formula breaks as well but it seems like if I delete anything else it's fine.

[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d-dS4Bxm4btl5OdASYjrMohBSF7mirmIONwiE0fs3Es/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: Example Data-Add Log]

[image: Example Data-Subtract Log]

[image: Example Data-Add/Subtract Log Results]

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time answering so be gentle :)

I think I understand what you're trying to do and managed to find a simpler solution than to bog down a giant nested query formula.

I created a separate tab named Count and there you list the Unique ID's of all products that have ever been added before. Then you add a column there for the number of times that product has been added. Next to it another column for how many times that product has been subtracted. Then finally another column for the balance difference, which is your leftover stock.

You then use a simple query on your Results tab which shows only products that have 1 or more in stock. Simples :)

OK I'm just now realizing I edited your sample sheet. Oops. Oh well, the formula's are there for the new Count tab as well as the Results Tab.

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=FILTER('Add Log'!A2:D, NOT(COUNTIF('Subtract Log'!A2:A, 'Add Log'!A2:A)))
```

[image]